# Wrong coordinate format (wgs84) or am I missing something?

Tags: ruby, wgs84

Dummy question here. I'm developing an app that fetches location-aware info. I'm getting location coordinates in following manner: lat=+aaa.bb.cc.dd&lon=+aaa.bb.cc.dd&datum=wgs84

How do I convert those coordinates into standard latitude longitude with single dot. Now it looks as if client is requesting an ip address lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wgs84 = '123.12.34.56'
deg, minute, second, fraction = wgs84.split(/\./).map(&:to_i)      # Ruby 1.9
deg, minute, second, fraction = wgs84.split(/\./).map {|x| x.to_i} # Ruby 1.8
deg += minute / 60.0 + second / 3600.0 + fraction / 360000.0
puts deg    # => 123.20970370370371
```

Takes the string with the wgs84 coordinate in it, splits it on the periods, converts the results from text `'34'` to numeric `34`, and then does the division necessary to convert the minutes, seconds, and fractions of seconds to floating point adjustments added to the latitude (or longitude).

Comment: Just a quibble, but doesn't 123.12.34.56 mean 123d12m34.56s ?  Where do the hours come in in WGS coordinates ?  Isn't correct solution 123+12/60+34.56/3600 ?

Comment: It could well be... honestly, I'm unfamiliar with WGS... looking online, it appears you are correct. Fixing the math.

Answer (score 1):

Emboldened by @Myrddin's near-agreement that he made a small mistake, I'm posting an answer in a blatant attempt to gather rep.

I suspect that

```
123.12.34.56
```

should be interpreted as 123d12m34.56s and converted to decimal degrees like this:

```
123+12/60+34.56/3600
```